# Azure WebApps - Are they patched by Microsoft?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If you have a Virtual Machine you are required to apply patches every Patch Tuesday and ensure the OS is up to date to prevent security issues.

If you get a PAAS Azure WebApp do Microsoft take care of patching the underlying OS?

If so would you see downtime when this happens?  Or are all the apps on that Host OS moved to another Host in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, that is kind of the point of PaaS. Azure takes care of the patches for the OS.

As for an answer to your other questions, this GitHub issue is quite good: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/63.

> Most updates can be performed without affecting your services running on the platform’s infrastructure. For this update, you’ll notice a restart of your web apps, the same that takes place during our regular monthly OS update. Our goal is to avoid service interruptions and, as with every upgrade to the service, we will be monitoring the health of the platform during the rollout.

Your apps are moved to another update domain transparently while the patch is applied to the update domain that hosted your app. It does cause an app restart of course.

Comment: Very interesting.  So when it says "the same that takes place during our regular monthly OS update" does that mean that the regular patch Tuesday works by moving all apps to a new patched OS.  This restarts the app but avoids downtime due to OS reboots?

Comment: Yeah your app won't go down due to OS restart since it has already been moved to another host before that happens.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I couldn't find this info anywhere! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a the blog we just published describing what goes on behind App Service updates - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/01/18/demystifying-the-magic-behind-app-service-os-updates/

Comment: Is there an updated version of this info somewhere?  MS removed the blog!  ty